# android- jquery mobile using web view instead of phone gap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile concept. I am using the web view instead of phone gap for displaying the html file(jquery mobile). is it better way or any disadvantages when i am using the web view. please can anybody help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a webview only permits you to access objects and events available to Javascript; no access to main hardware features, such as GPS or Bluetooth (unless you write a translation layer between your Java and Javascript - at which point, you might as well use PhoneGap).  PhoneGap exposes your device's hardware to the javascript layer.  If you only want to display a webpage or web app, a webview is enough, otherwise I'd go with PhoneGap.

Comment: is it possible to access the sqlite(Local data base) using the web view?

Comment: yes, but I'd test on a couple of platforms first. Android more or less supports the HTML5 specs, and so you should be able to use the sqlite db objects available to you via HTML5.